# Can the PayPal REST API display order items with tax included?

Tags: c#, rest, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

i've managed to set up the site i'm working on to process payments using the paypal c# rest api sdk (https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-dotnet).

the bit i'm struggling with (other than the documentation which is unbelievably bad...) is how to get my order summary to display my basket line items including the tax and if paypal work on the basis shipping will/won't include tax?

a sample order with a total of £150.99 contains:

a single product costing £145 inc tax of £24.17
a shipping cost of £5.99 inc tax of £1.00

this is what i'm sending off to paypal:

```
{
  "intent": "sale",
  "payer": {
        "payment_method": "paypal"
  },
  "transactions": [
        {
              "amount": {
                    "currency": "GBP",
                    "total": "150.99",
                    "details": {
                          "shipping": "5.99",
                          "subtotal": "120.83",
                          "tax": "24.17"
                    }
              },
              "description": "My Site",
              "item_list": {
                    "items": [
                          {
                                "quantity": "1",
                                "name": "My Item",
                                "price": "120.83",
                                "currency": "GBP",
                                "sku": "123"
                          }
                    ],
                    "shipping_address": {
                          "recipient_name": "My Name",
                          "line1": "My address",
                          "line2": "",
                          "city": "London",
                          "country_code": "GB",
                          "postal_code": "XX XXX",
                          "phone": "00 0000 0000"
                    }
              }
        }
  ],
  "redirect_urls": {
        "return_url": "http://return",
        "cancel_url": "http://cancel"
  }
}
```

this works in paypal and i can process the payment but the items display as this in the order summary:

```
My Item £120.83
Item number: 123
Item price: £120.83
Quantity: 1

Item total £120.83
VAT: £24.17
Postage and packaging: £5.99

Total £150.99 GBP
```

it's ok, but i'd rather show the price including the vat - is this possible? i've tried using the price inc tax when setting the line item but get the following error:

```
Item amount must add up to specified amount subtotal (or total if amount details not specified
```

it feels like i'm soooo close... any ideas?

Comment: impossible, paypal needs it without vat.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the subtotal equal to the total and "tax" : "0" you can define the item price including VAT.
This is what I've seen most platforms use, since Paypal takes fees off your final total anyways. Furthermore it prevents possible rounding errors.